# Problem with OnMeasureItem()

Tags: mfc, message, clistctrl

I used OnMeasureItem() in my MFC ListControl to increase the height of the rows, and added WM_ON_MEASUREITEM() message in the Map. THe code I used is as follows:

void CListCtrlTestDlg::OnMeasureItem(int nIDCtl, LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMeasureItemStruct)

{

if( nIDCtl == IDC_LIST1 )//IDC_LIST1 is my ListControl ID

```
  {

      lpMeasureItemStruct->itemHeight += 20;

  }
```

}

It doesn't Work. Any suggestion what the problem is???

Thank You!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to set **'Owner Draw Fixed'** property to **'TRUE'**. Works fine now :)